# target javascript function in clicked element

Tags: javascript

sorry for question, I cant figure it out.
If:

```
<body onclick="myFunction(event)">
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<button>This is a button</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(event) { 
    var x = event.target;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.tagName;
}
</script>
</body>
```

how can I display the function result in current HTML element, which I clicked on? Not in "demo".

Comment: `x.innerHTML`  ?

Comment: `x` is a tag name, I have tried `document.getElementsByTagName[0].x.innerHTML = x.tagName;` - does not work

Comment: @MichalKotus, use `x.innerHTML = x.tagName;` That is what *Suresh Atta* is saying.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your HTML Code To be :

```
onclick="myFunction(this);"
```

In Your Case it will be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="mFunction(this);" ID='TER' value="Heeeey">
</body>
<script>
    function mFunction(obj){
        obj.value = "My Result" ; 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have done with `event.target.nodeName`

```
<body onclick="myFunction(event)">
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<button>This is a button</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(event) { 
    var x = event.target;
    x.innerHTML = x.nodeName;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: *how can I display the function result in current HTML element, which I clicked on? Not in "demo".* ... Did you misread the question?

Comment: I dont want the result in `document.getElementById("demo")`, but if I click on `H1`, I need the result in `<h1></h1>` element

Comment: @MichalKotus, you received a good answer(not the one above, the other one is good), and also a good comment(the first one under your question). What is the problem?

Comment: event.target.innerHTML = event.target.nodeName;

Comment: @WaqasAhmed, wouldn't it be nicer like `x.innerHTML` ?

Comment: @MichalKotus yes you can do as well :)

Comment: @WaqasAhmed, also no need for `nodeName`, because `tagName` works very well

Comment: That's all upto you i have just put solution.Hope you have done.

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't have a result in the sense that it doesn't return anything. But in general, if you are trying to set the innerHTML of the object that you just clicked to 'something' you should be able to do

```
event.target.innerHTML = 'something'
```